# Linkify custom link in function

Tags: jquery, linkify

I am trying to create custom links based on different buttons using this html.

```
<input type="text" name="coachid" id="textbox1" value="22984">
<button class="txtLinky" id="Mickey">Mickey</button><br/>       
<div id="linkified"></div>  
<button class="txtLinky" id="Donald">Donald</button><br/>
<div id="linkified"></div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
$(".txtLinky").click(function () {                              
            $('#linkified').html('http:www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringpId=' + $("#textbox1").val());

            $('#linkified').linkify({
               tagName: 'a',
               target: '_blank',
               newLine: '\n'
            }); 

            $('#linkified').css('padding', '100px');
            });
```

Not sure how to get the second button to work. The first button will work but not the second.

here is http://jsfiddle.net/VFhK9/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple `div` elements with `id="linkified"`.

`id` is unique; you cannot have more than one control with the same id.

You could change your `id` attributes to `class` attributes and do something like this:

## ***HTML***

---

```
<input type="text" name="coachid" id="textbox1" value="22984" />
<br />
<br/>
<button class="txtLinky" id="Mickey">Click Link</button>
<br/>
<div class="linkified">value</div>
<br/>
<button class="txtLinky" id="Donald">Click Link</button>
<br/>
<div class="linkified">value</div>
```

## ***JQUERY***

---

```
$(".txtLinky").on("click", function () 
{
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr("id"),
        text = $("#textbox1").val();
    
    $this
        .nextAll('.linkified:first')
        .css({ padding: '10px' })
        .html
        (
            'http://www.example.com/'
            + id
            + '?referringRepId='
            + text
        )
        .linkify
        ({
            tagName: 'a',
            target: '_blank',
            newLine: '\n'
        });
});
```

## ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzp4n/)***