# jQuery button id to div id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create links to a site by way of button class and ids. I am trying to create a clickable html link for each one by way of div ids.

Here is the html

```
<nav id="menu">
    <div id="app">
        <ul class="List"><li><span>Enter Number below</span>
            </li>
            <div id="number">
            <input type="text" name="number" id="textbox1" value="22984">
            </div>              
                <li><span>Disney</span>
                <ul id="programs">                  
                      <li><span>Lands</span>
                          <ul id="10min">

                             <li><span>Adventureland</span>
                                <ul id="Adventureland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
<button class="txtLinky" id="Adventureland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                                <div id="linkified">value</div>     
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li><span>Frontierland</span>
                                <ul id="Frontierland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                   <input type="hidden" name="basic1" id="basic1" value="TMTDeluxe"/>
                                     <button class="txtLinky" id="Frontierland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                            <div id="linkified">value</div> 
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li><span>Fantasyland</span>
                                <ul id="Fantasyland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                    <button class="txtLinky" id="Fantasyland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                            <div id="linkified">value</div>     
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                             <li><span>Tomorrowland</span>
                                <ul id="Tomorrowland">
                                   <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                    <button class="txtLinky" id="Tomorrowland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                            <div id="linkified">value</div>     
                                    </ul>
                             </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                   </li>

                </ul>
            </li>               
        </ul>
```

Here is the javascript

```
 $(".txtLinky").click(function () {

   // Get the Text from TextArea and give that to the Div.
    $('#linkified').html('http://www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val());

    // Now, linkify all the links present in the Text.
    $('#linkified').linkify({
        tagName: 'a',
        target: '_blank',
        newLine: '\n'
    });


$('#linkified').css('padding', '10px');
});
```

I need each button to update the div id below it rather than the first initial div id. Is there a way to make this work?

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/VFhK9/6/

Comment: You have already asked this question [Linkify custom link in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919462/linkify-custom-link-in-function). The answer is going to be the same. You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: You can't set multiple tag with the same id. Id is unique. For example you can't do that: <ul id="Tomorrowland"> and <button class="txtLinky" id="Tomorrowland"> .

Comment: @AmitKumar or use multiple classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i would like to note that **having multiple elements with the same id is a bad habit**. **I would make them classes**. But check the following code if you like:

```
$(".txtLinky").click(function () {

    // Get the Text from TextArea and give that to the Div.
    $(this).parent().children('#linkified').html('http://www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val());

    // Now, linkify all the links present in the Text.
    $(this).parent().children('#linkified').linkify({
        tagName: 'a',
        target: '_blank',
        newLine: '\n'
    });


    $(this).parent().children('#linkified').css('padding', '10px');
});
```

[This is a working samlpe based on your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb2Ph/)

Comment: I think this will work!

Comment: Though my answer stands as a valid answer, i think calling the `siblings` method suggested by @user3003216 will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` and go from that to its next element. Change your code into this:

```
$(".txtLinky").click(function () {
       // Get the Text from TextArea and give that to the Div.
        $(this).siblings('#linkified').html('http://www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val());

        // Now, linkify all the links present in the Text.
        $(this).siblings('#linkified').linkify({
            tagName: 'a',
            target: '_blank',
            newLine: '\n'
        });

        $(this).siblings('#linkified').css('padding', '10px');
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFhK9/7/)..

Answer (score 0):

as id should be unique.or use class. i have replace your id with class.
so your code

```
<nav id="menu">
        <div id="app">
            <ul class="List"><li><span>Enter Number below</span>
                </li>
                <div id="number">
                <input type="text" name="number" id="textbox1" value="22984">
                </div>              
                    <li><span>Disney</span>
                    <ul id="programs">                  
                          <li><span>Lands</span>
                              <ul id="10min">

                                 <li><span>Adventureland</span>
                                    <ul id="Adventureland">
                                       <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
<button class="txtLinky" id="Adventureland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                                    <div class="linkified">value</div>      
                                        </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li><span>Frontierland</span>
                                    <ul id="Frontierland">
                                       <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                       <input type="hidden" name="basic1" id="basic1" value="TMTDeluxe"/>
                                         <button class="txtLinky" id="Frontierland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                                <div class="linkified">value</div>  
                                        </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li><span>Fantasyland</span>
                                    <ul id="Fantasyland">
                                       <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                        <button class="txtLinky" id="Fantasyland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                                <div class="linkified">value</div>      
                                        </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li><span>Tomorrowland</span>
                                    <ul id="Tomorrowland">
                                       <li class="Label">&nbsp;</li>
                                        <button class="txtLinky" id="Tomorrowland">Click Link</button><br/>
                                                <div class="linkified">value</div>      
                                        </ul>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                       </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>               
            </ul>
```

js

```
$(".txtLinky").click(function () {

       // Get the Text from TextArea and give that to the Div.
        $(this).siblings('.linkified').html('http://www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' + $("#textbox1").val());

        // Now, linkify all the links present in the Text.
        $(this).siblings('.linkified').linkify({
            tagName: 'a',
            target: '_blank',
            newLine: '\n'
        });


            $(this).siblings('.linkified').css('padding', '10px');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/VFhK9/10/)

Answer (score 0):

here is a to jsFiddle i changed the ID to Class in the divs becouse an ID is an Identifyer and can't be repeated twice [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/VFhK9/8/)

```
$(".txtLinky").click(function () {
var link ='http://www.example.com/' + $(this).attr('id') + '?referringRepId=' +$("#textbox1").val();
       $(this).parent().children('.linkified').html(link);
        $('.linkified').linkify({
            tagName: 'a',
            target: '_blank',
            newLine: '\n'
        });

   $(this).parent().children('.linkified').css('padding', '10px');
});
```